# Fan-out / fan-in - closing result channel

Tags: kotlin, channel, coroutine, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm producing items, consuming from multiple co-routines and pushing back to resultChannel. Producer is closing its channel after last item.

The code never finishes as resultChannel is never being closed. How to detect and properly finish iteration so `hasNext()` return `false`?

```
val inputData = (0..99).map { "Input$it" }
val threads = 10

val bundleProducer = produce<String>(CommonPool, threads) {
    inputData.forEach { item ->
        send(item)
        println("Producing: $item")
    }

    println("Producing finished")
    close()
}

val resultChannel = Channel<String>(threads)

repeat(threads) {
    launch(CommonPool) {
        bundleProducer.consumeEach {
            println("CONSUMING $it")
            resultChannel.send("Result ($it)")
        }
    }
}

val iterator = object : Iterator<String> {
    val iterator = resultChannel.iterator()
    override fun hasNext() = runBlocking { iterator.hasNext() }
    override fun next() = runBlocking { iterator.next() }
}.asSequence()

println("Starting interation...")

val result = iterator.toList()

println("finish: ${result.size}")
```

Comment: The hackish way to do it I've found is to .take(100) on the resulting sequence but I'm not sure in what state it leaves the underlying structures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run a coroutine that awaits for the consumers to finish and then closes the `resultChannel`.

First, rewrite the code that starts the consumers to save the `Job`s:

```
val jobs = (1..threads).map {
    launch(CommonPool) {
        bundleProducer.consumeEach {
            println("CONSUMING $it")
            resultChannel.send("Result ($it)")
        }
    }
}
```

And then run another coroutine that closes the channel once all the `Job`s are done:

```
launch(CommonPool) {
    jobs.forEach { it.join() }
    resultChannel.close()
}
```